# Why are heuristics proposed?

Tags: algorithm

I have a small confusion with the nature of heuristics.

We know that heuristics need not give correct outputs for all input instances.
But then, why are heuristics proposed??

Comment: You can't always compute a "correct" result. Think about the artificial intelligence of a deep game for example.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic. It belong to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Taking your girlfriend to a fancy restaurant would be perfect, but if you can't afford, you can buy a bottle of wine and cook some dinner and it will be good enough. ;-)

Comment: @IceArdor: not appropriate for SO, but not so inappropriate that you didn't answer the question !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heuristics are used to trade off performance (usually execution speed, but also memory consumption) with potential accuracy or generality. For example, your anti virus software uses heuristics to characterize what a virus might look like, and can take advantage of that piece of information to determine which files it should spend more time analyzing. A good heuristic has the property that it can save substantial time with minimal cost.

In graph traversal theory, a heuristic for an A* search algorithm need not be perfect. It just needs to have a predicted cost function h(x) that is less than or equal to the true cost to the goal state in order to guarantee an optimal solution. The closer h(x) equals the true cost, the quicker an optimal solution will be found.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer has helped me to clear my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you an example which might help you understand the importance of heuristics.
In Artificial Intelligence, search problems are mainly classified as blind search and directed search. Blind search is where you make use of algorithms such as BFS and DFS and there is a reason they are called blind search, they don't have any knowledge about the direction you should go, you just have to explore and explore until you reach the goal node, imagine the time and space complexity for those algorithms.

Now if you look at the directed search algorithm such as A*, where you have some kind of heuristic function or in simple terms an assumption about which direction you should take the next step.

Although heuristics does not guarantee the best result but rather will try to give you a better solution and sometimes even the best. There are so many classes of problems (Ex. games you play) where a better solution does the task rather than wasting so much time and space in finding the best solution.
I hope it helps.